# SQL query to get monthly sales per product, including products with no sales

Tags: sql-server

Let's say we have a Product table (product_id, product_name) and a Sales table (product_id, date, qty, amount).

What sql query would return the monthly sales per product, and **include products with no sales**?

(I'm using sql server if that makes any difference).

Clarification: I want a row for each possible month/product tuple. If there was no sales for a given month/product it should show zero qty/sales

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if this is what you're looking for (adjust as needed):

```
set nocount on

--Declare a months table (or use a Date Dimension table)
Declare @Months Table (MonthNumber tinyint, MonthName varchar(20))
insert into @Months (MonthNumber,MonthName) values
(1,'January'),
(2,'February'),
(3,'March'),
(4,'April'),
(5,'May'),
(6,'June'),
(7,'July'),
(8,'August'),
(9,'September'),
(10,'October'),
(11,'November'),
(12,'December')

--Declare a products table
Declare @Products table (Id int, ProductName Varchar(20)) 
insert into @Products (Id, ProductName)
values(1,'Widgets'),(2,'Thingamabob')

Declare @Sales table (product_id int, [date] Date, qty int, amount decimal(11,2))
insert into @Sales (product_id, [date], qty, amount)
values(1,'2017-01-01',1,100.00),(2,'2017-02-01',1,200.00),(2,'2017-06-01',2,300)

--Select Months and CROSS JOIN to Products, then
--LEFT JOIN to Sales.  Use ISNULL to return zeros
--for months/products with no sales
SELECT m.MONTHNUMBER
    ,m.MonthName
    ,P.ProductName
    ,ISNULL(SUM(QTY), 0) AS QTY
    ,ISNULL(SUM(AMOUNT), 0) AS AMOUNT
FROM @Months m
CROSS JOIN @Products p
LEFT JOIN @Sales s ON DatePart(MONTH, [date]) = M.MonthNumber
    AND S.product_id = P.ID
GROUP BY m.MonthNumber
    ,m.MonthName
    ,P.ProductName
ORDER BY M.MonthNumber
    ,m.MonthName
    ,P.ProductName
```

---

```
| MONTHNUMBER | MonthName | ProductName | QTY | AMOUNT |
|-------------|-----------|-------------|-----|--------|
| 1           | January   | Thingamabob | 0   | 0.00   |
| 1           | January   | Widgets     | 1   | 100.00 |
| 2           | February  | Thingamabob | 1   | 200.00 |
| 2           | February  | Widgets     | 0   | 0.00   |
| 3           | March     | Thingamabob | 0   | 0.00   |
| 3           | March     | Widgets     | 0   | 0.00   |
| 4           | April     | Thingamabob | 0   | 0.00   |
| 4           | April     | Widgets     | 0   | 0.00   |
| 5           | May       | Thingamabob | 0   | 0.00   |
| 5           | May       | Widgets     | 0   | 0.00   |
| 6           | June      | Thingamabob | 2   | 300.00 |
| 6           | June      | Widgets     | 0   | 0.00   |
| 7           | July      | Thingamabob | 0   | 0.00   |
| 7           | July      | Widgets     | 0   | 0.00   |
| 8           | August    | Thingamabob | 0   | 0.00   |
| 8           | August    | Widgets     | 0   | 0.00   |
| 9           | September | Thingamabob | 0   | 0.00   |
| 9           | September | Widgets     | 0   | 0.00   |
| 10          | October   | Thingamabob | 0   | 0.00   |
| 10          | October   | Widgets     | 0   | 0.00   |
| 11          | November  | Thingamabob | 0   | 0.00   |
| 11          | November  | Widgets     | 0   | 0.00   |
| 12          | December  | Thingamabob | 0   | 0.00   |
| 12          | December  | Widgets     | 0   | 0.00   |
```

**Note:** The OP did not indicate they wanted a solution that takes the *year* into consideration, so my solution does not deal with the notion of a *year* when aggregating the data.  If the month is January (regardless of year), the counts go in the January bucket.

UPDATE: To clarify a bit further, I want a row for each possible month/product tuple. If there was no sales for a given month/product it should show zero qty/sales

Comment: Perfect! Any reason why you use cross apply instead of cross join here?

Comment: @Clement - you are correct - `CROSS JOIN` better matches my intentions - I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is what a [LEFT JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894(v=office.12).aspx) does.

Getting **every** row from the left table and the **matched** rows from the right table. For any rows of the left table that does not have a match on the right one (in your case, for every product with no sales) you will get `NULL` values.

The following code:

```
with products (id, name) as 
(
    select 1, 'p1' union all
    select 2, 'p2' union all
    select 3, 'p3'
)
, sales (pid, date, qty, amount)  as
(
    select 1, '20170101', 3, 100  union all
    select 2, '20170101', 4, 200  union all
    select 2, '20170102', 5, 500 

)

select p.id, p.name, sales.date, sales.qty, sales.amount
from products p left join  sales on p.id = sales.pid                           
order by p.id, sales.date
```

Generates the following result:

[image]

For product id = 3, there are no sales in the source data but you still see the product listed in the results.

> EDIT:

Consider making use of the calendar table from Aaron Bertrand's [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/).
You can check out a working demo [here](http://rextester.com/CXCI68844).

You have a list of month, product and sales for each month of 2017, for each product.

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear enough. I want a row for each possible month/product tuple. If there was no sales for a given month/product it should show zero qty/sales

Comment: You need a list of 12 month per year? You will need a date calendar for that. The left join logic still stands :)

Comment: I'm ok with a calendar table. However I don't see how your answer solves the problem. For a start there is no month grouping.

Comment: @Clement it might be good to add these clarifications as an edit to your question.